# Location of ingested data through geomesa-hbase ingest command

Tags: hdfs, hbase, geomesa

I am totally new to geomesa ,I am using geomes-hbase-2.11-2.3.1 and I have followed below site for data ingestion.
https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-examples-gdelt.html 
It successfully ingested data into hdfs and geomesa-hbase extract command also works fine but I don't know path/location of where this data is exactly stored.

Answer (score 0):

Data ingested into HBase is stored in HBase under its root directory (see the hbase.rootdir in the hbase-site.xml config file).  Depending on how that's configured, you may be able to find the underlying storefiles which contain the data you ingested.  That said, the point of putting the data into HBase would be to query the database and leverage its benefits.